# Android Studio - VideoView in ViewPager preview problem

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-videoview, preload, android-viewpager2

I'm inflating and running VideoViews in ViewPager2 via RecyclerView.Adapter. waiting for videos to load is so boring so i need a preloader how can i do that ?

This is my code:

```
String link = "https://media.istockphoto.com/videos/vertical-video-portrait-of-woman-standing-being-covered-in-coloured-video-id1255001964";
String link1 = "https://media.istockphoto.com/videos/aerial-vertical-video-valley-view-cave-and-fairy-chimneys-ancient-video-id1306879287";
String link2 = "https://media.istockphoto.com/videos/underground-and-overground-view-of-4k-vertical-timelapse-of-an-sour-video-id1203927026";
String link3 = "https://v77.tiktokcdn.com/562c58c18d346d0284b3604807e8f89d/60c74679/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037c001/edb2701ce28b4ccc843809c5cea87b66/?a=1233&br=1608&bt=804&cd=0%7C0%7C1&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2021061406062101019020921612F5BAA4&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=M2ZrOztrNm5zNDMzOzczM0ApZTZkPGRkZGVoNzk5ZmQ5NGdgZ2ticjU1Y2RgLS0vMTRzczEtX2E2LmAuNGJhNDNiLmE6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=";
String link4 = "https://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/6dd393d411e959580368c0229596fba5/60c7479f/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037c001/b34ba40288a240f391fcc3e22af93a2e/?a=1233&br=2740&bt=1370&cd=0%7C0%7C1&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=202106140611360101890720343CF4FEB9&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=MzlnZThseWU5NTMzODczM0ApZjg0N2hlNDw8N2Y2aTxkNGdnMGJpXjZsbnFgLS1kMTRzczEtNjZgNjViNjMyNTQ1NC86Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=";

ViewPager2 viewPager;
List<VideoData> list;
VideoAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    
    //viewPager.setClipChildren(true);
    //viewPager.setClipToPadding(true);
    //viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    //viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new VideoData(link));
    list.add(new VideoData(link1));
    list.add(new VideoData(link2));
    list.add(new VideoData(link3));
    list.add(new VideoData(link4));
    adapter = new VideoAdapter(list);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what does mean boot loader ? you mean placeholder or something preview before load?

Comment: @TheMJ yes i meant preloader, sorry for my english.

Comment: @TheMJ I want to prepare the next video while watching a video